# Using Data From SQLite database in android

Tags: android, sql, database

I am currently working on a diet app in android. So, I have planned to have a food database which could store information like calories, protein, fats, carbohydrates of food items. I don't know how to use SQL databases, that's why please tell me how can i use that data....for ex - if user searches for a food, say apple, in a search bar then how could the nutritional information of apple could be displayed.

Please provide me the source code for doing that...if you still feel confused about my question see the "[myFitnessPal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myfitnesspal.android&hl=en)" android app and how the entries are made in that.

If you know any kind of references i could use kindly suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: question is too board to answer.

Comment: This isn't a code-request site. Just google for `android sqlite` and get a zillion tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that provides the details you need: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

I can't provide any code for you, as you have to think of what features your app should have and according to that you have to build up a database structure. But basically in your code you open a database which is then represented as a `SQLiteDatabase` object in your code. You can then run sql queries on the database with the `execSQL` function.

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of code to show to get something basic working. I would suggest following [Vogella's SQLite Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) to get you started.

One thing in this tutorial that stumped me was he seemed to suggest that you need a `SQLiteOpenHelper` for each table. In fact what he meant was the `SQLiteOpenHelper` is for a single database and you would have a separate static class for each table where you would do something like:

```
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        MyTable.onCreate(database);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        MyTable.onUpdate(db, oldVersion, newVersion)
    }

}
```

The MyTable class contains the methods to create and update the database for that specific table.

```
public class MyTable {

   private static final String TABLE_NAME = "example";
   private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";

   private static String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)";

   public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
       database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
   }

   ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will go through the vogella's tutorial and try to improve my knowledge about android database then i will create some great code for my app